# Fuzi XML parser is not working. Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I am attempting a migration to Swift 3 ( an utterly horrible experience.  I couldn't be more furious.  What is with this mess of debugging messages?  Arrrg!)

Anyhow, are any of you using Fuzi XML parser?  Have you managed to get it working with Swift 3?  Documentation seems to suggest that its working with Xcode 8 (Swift 3), but not for me.  I'll keep fighting with it if others have succeeded, otherwise I am about to abandon Fuzi and rewrite my code with another parser which is going to be a hellish experience given that I am struggling to filter through the mess of messages in the xCode debugger.

Comment: Post error log,some.

Comment: The error log is a separate issue.  Basically what is happening, is that after updating the pod and installing it in a new project, its still forcing me to do the conversion of Fuzi's code to Swift 3.  Acknowledging the possibility that I am doing something wrong, I wanted to find out if anyone else has succeeded before I waste more time on this.

Comment: what is the ios target in podfile?

Comment: Last I tried it was at iOS 10.0.  I have tried everything from the Fuzi provided 8.0 all the way up to current 10.0 version.   Here is the Fuzi link:  https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi

Comment: try iOS 10.0. and do `pod update --verbose`

Comment: Thank you very much!  You have saved me a pile of time.  I guess the key was "pod update ---verbose"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP upgraded to the Swift 3, but did not updated the pods.

`pod install` just installs the new pods.

Since OP upgraded to Swift 3.0, he has to mention iOS 10 in the `podfile` and do `pod update` to update the pods to recent version.

Comment: No, I actually did that.  What I left out was the " --verbose".  You must do "pod update --verbose"

Comment: `--verbose` is not necessary. It is used to see log of current `pod` process.

Comment: I am absolutely certain I did "pod update" yesterday.  Anyhow, problem solved.  All is good.  Thanks again.